# Passing sed to a temporary variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to bulk change some files in bash that have spaces and unwanted endings to their extension.

For example from

abc.pdf.!ut.!ut

to

abc.pdf

I will show whole progress in case I made something harder than it should actually be. So at first I started with something like

```
for file in `find /Users/phwd/Desktop/Film\ Sheet\ Music\ Scores\ 2  *.\!ut.\!ut`;
do
 mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\!\ut\.\!\ut/\1/'`;
done
```

The above did not work for spaces when sending for mv so I changed to this

```
find /Users/phwd/Desktop/Film\ Sheet\ Music\ Scores\ 2  *.\!ut.\!ut | while read file
do 
    mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\!\ut\.\!\ut/\1/'`;
done
```

This worked almost but mv started saying an arbitrary message

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

I am over thinking something ?

Comment: Execute the script with sh -xv sciptfile, it will show you the commands being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you just want to remove the ending `!ut.!ut` I would suggest something like this:

```
for file in `find ...`; do
  mv "$file" "${file%.\!ut.\!ut}"
done
```

In this case the shell does its job and removes the ending. This feature is called *parameter expansion*.